# If you travel fast enough towards a light source, will you fall into a kugelblitz?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, redshift

A kugelblitz is simply a special case of black hole, one that's formed from photons instead of fermions.  Thanks of course to mass-energy equivalence, enough photon energy in a small enough region can warp spacetime enough to create a black hole.

The higher energy the photons, the fewer are needed to create a black hole.  And indeed, my understanding is that a single photon whose wavelength equaled the Planck length would effectively collapse into a (very small) kugelblitz.

But... photon energy is all relative.  If you are speeding away from a high-energy photon, it will become redshifted and therefore lower energy.  If you speed towards a low-energy photon, it will become blueshifted and therefore higher energy.

Theoretically, then, if you're traveling very close to the speed of light towards an emitted photon or photons, those photons would be blueshifted into dangerous, high-energy frequencies relative to you.

If you were to travel *really* close to the speed of light toward a light source, then, couldn't those photons become so high energy relative to you that a small number of them would form a kugelblitz (which you would then get sucked into)?

If that's the case, what would an outside observer witness?

Comment: What about the energy you will be spending getting close to the speed of light?

Comment: I was thinking about the converse, where someone is creating a kugelblitz with all gamma lasers coming from one hemisphere and I'm speeding away from it in the other direction. So the lasers would be redshifted for me. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn2hb.png) I'm trying to understand why I would still observe the creation of a black hole.

Answer (score 5):

No. Regardless of how blue shifted or how high energy a photon is, it is not a black hole.

The horizon is an invariant global feature of the spacetime. It cannot exist in some coordinates and not in others. This is one thing that distinguishes an event horizon from a Rindler horizon.

While for the formation of a black hole it is necessary to have the energy inside its own Schwarzschild radius, that is a necessary and not a sufficient condition. The energy density is just the time time component of the stress energy tensor. The momentum density and pressure are also important components. In frames where the energy density is very high the momentum density is correspondingly high. That prevents the formation of the black hole.

Comment: You are answering the "single photon". Is it true for a light source too?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Sorry Sir, I didn’t mean to criticize. I just wanted to run them by you. I’ve deleted my comments.